# why phpmyadmin shows list of files instead of database?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, wamp

When i open localhost/phpmyadmin. it shows me list of all files instead of the database. Why it happens ? Any help will be appreciated. below is my screenshot for phpmyadmin
[image]

Comment: Is there `index.php` file?

Comment: PHP is not running on your machine, so the server didn't find a index.html and just displays all available files.

Comment: In project also shows me all listing it doesn't run index file

Comment: Install PHP interpreter.

Comment: You added the WAMP tag, did you install WAMPServer or XAMPP or did you install Apache/PHP/MySQL manually yourself one at a time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the webserver (which I'm guessing is Apache because of the WAMP tag and because of the look of this list) hasn't been told to use `index.php` as a default file and is configured to show a directory listing instead. It generally means you haven't properly (or fully, anyway) configured your PHP installation, because generally the PHP installation instructions I've seen include this step (or do it automatically). So it's possible you additionally haven't installed PHP at all; which you can quickly test by clicking the `index.php` link and seeing whether you get a log in page or screen full of gibberish. Anyway, WAMP includes PHP, so I presume at this point that you've just got the index.php configuration problem, so:

In your Apache configuration, find the line for `DirectoryIndex`. You'll need to add index.php to the list. For example, mine looks like:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html home.pl index.cgi
```

You probably don't need all of those and should only add index.php; don't just copy and paste my line, it's just given as an example.

This is the list of files that Apache looks for to run as the main page of a folder/subdirectory. If it can't find any of the listed files then it generally shows the listing of all files in that directory (which is controlled by [mod_autoindex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html), if you're interested in learning more).

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the comments, here is a list of things you might need to check:

- No PHP installed
- You have to define DirectoryIndex if you are running Apache
- Again, if running Apache, you have to ensure that your PHP mod is correctly loaded
- Finally, still with Apache, ensure that you correctly load the PHP module for files ending with (.php|.inc)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

uncomment below line

```
LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

then restart apache